# How do you generalize a function to a list of nodes in a collection?

Tags: anylogic

I try to access the coordinates of the node lists stored in the collection through the functions getnodeX and getnodeY.

But I don't know how to generalize the function and apply it to the node list of collection the same way.

The model is not simplified as you try to access the coordinates of the node by defining node.getX() node1.getX().

If you know how to solve it, please advise me

[image]
[image]

Comment: i don't understand your question, but you should do Flag/3.0 otherwise you will get the wrong value..

Comment: I think you massively overcomplicate your code. What are you trying to achieve? Just get the y coordinates of a node?